PPO only working with a single epoch and unclipped loss
I'm attempting to implement PPO to beat cartpole-v2, I manage to get it working if I keep things as A2C (That is, without clipped loss and a single epoch), when I use clipped loss and more than one epoch it doesn't learn, have been trying to find the issue in my implementation for about a week but I can't find what's wrong.
Full Code
Here is the function responsible for optimizing:
def finish_episode():
    # Calculating losses and performing backprop
    R = 0
    saved_actions = actor.saved_actions
    returns = []
    epsilon = 0.3
    num_epochs = 1 # When num_epochs is greater than one my network won't learn

    for r in actor.rewards[::-1]:
        R = r + 0.99 * R # Gamma is 0.99
        returns.insert(0, R)
    returns = torch.tensor(returns, device=device)
    returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + eps)

    old_probs, state_values, states, actions = zip(*saved_actions)

    old_probs = torch.stack(old_probs).to(device)
    state_values = torch.stack(state_values).to(device)
    states = torch.stack(states).to(device)
    actions = torch.stack(actions).to(device)

    advantages = returns - state_values.squeeze()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        new_probs = actor(states).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()

        ratios = new_probs / old_probs

        surr1 = ratios * advantages
        surr2 = torch.clamp(ratios, 1 - epsilon, 1 + epsilon) * advantages

        #actor_loss = -torch.min(surr1, surr2).mean() # When using this (clipped) loss my network won't learn
        actor_loss = -surr1.mean()

        actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        actor_optimizer.step()

        if epoch == num_epochs - 1:
            critic_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(state_values.squeeze(), returns)
            
            critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
            critic_loss.backward(retain_graph=False)
            critic_optimizer.step()

    del actor.rewards[:]
    del actor.saved_actions[:]

Tried different hyperparameters, using gae as opposed to full monte carlo retuns/advantages, in combing through my code I can't see what's wrong.

In the function of state_action, instead of getting the probability itself, it is better to get the logarithm of the probability. So, your function should be:
def select_action(state):
    state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().to(device)
    mean = F.softmax(actor(state), dim=-1)       # This is the mean value of the output
    m = Categorical(mean)            # This is our distribution based on mean
    action = m.sample()
    probs = m.log_prob(action)       # This is the log_prob (I didn't change the name)
    state_value = critic(state)
    actor.saved_actions.append((probs.detach(), state_value, state, action.detach()))   # changed to probs.detach()
    return action.item()

Also, in the finish_episode function, you need to change the equation of the ratio:
ratios = torch.exp(new_probs - old_probs)

Also, for the problem of num_epochs, you are using the old state values for the policy update. You need to use the critic for update. Your code is modified as follow (check the comments):
def finish_episode():
    # Calculating losses and performing backprop
    R = 0
    saved_actions = actor.saved_actions
    returns = []
    epsilon = 0.2
    num_epochs = 3

    for r in actor.rewards[::-1]:
        R = r + 0.99 * R # Gamma is 0.99
        returns.insert(0, R)
    returns = torch.tensor(returns, device=device)
    returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + eps)

    old_probs, state_values, states, actions = zip(*saved_actions)

    old_probs = torch.stack(old_probs).to(device)
    state_values = torch.stack(state_values).to(device)
    states = torch.stack(states).to(device)
    actions = torch.stack(actions).to(device)
    values = critic(states).to(device).detach()    # value function is added and detached
    
    advantages = returns - values.squeeze()      # value function from critic added to advantage

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        values = critic(states).to(device)   # also, you need to pudate the critic in the loop
        new_probs = actor(states).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()

        # ratios = new_probs / old_probs
        ratios = torch.exp(new_probs - old_probs)

        surr1 = ratios * advantages
        surr2 = torch.clamp(ratios, 1 - epsilon, 1 + epsilon) * advantages

        actor_loss = -torch.min(surr1, surr2).mean()
        # actor_loss = -surr1.mean()
        
        actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        actor_optimizer.step()

        # if epoch == num_epochs - 1:
        critic_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(values.squeeze(), returns)       # it is changed from state_values to values
        
        critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        critic_optimizer.step()

    del actor.rewards[:]
    del actor.saved_actions[:]

I changed the learning rates:
actor_optimizer = optim.Adam(actor.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
critic_optimizer = optim.Adam(critic.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

I ran the code and got following results (just give it some time to run):
Episode 1330 Reward: 430.00 Average reward: 420.69
Episode 1340 Reward: 500.00 Average reward: 428.80
Episode 1350 Reward: 500.00 Average reward: 436.10
Episode 1360 Reward: 458.00 Average reward: 453.50
Episode 1370 Reward: 500.00 Average reward: 465.66
Episode 1380 Reward: 498.00 Average reward: 462.26
Episode 1390 Reward: 500.00 Average reward: 475.03
Solved, running reward is now 475.02882655892296 and the last episode runs to 500 timesteps

I am pretty sure, you can get better results after some hyperparameter tunning

After using log probs it still didn't work for me after changing num_epochs to be greater than one and using the clipped loss. However, it was also performing worse over all which got me to realize I wasn't applying the log function to the new probabilities, which then led me to realizing I wasn't using softmax either! So my ratio was my logit output/old_probs rather than new probabilities themselves! Thank you for inadvertently leading me to find the issue!

@yanis-falaki, I just did some edits. please use the latest edit I did. I erased your if statement in the finish_episode function. You need to use the critic to get the values, which you didn't.

It turned out that I was directly using my logits in place of the new probability when calculating the probability ratio.
So instead of:
new_probs = actor(states).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()

It should have been:
new_probs = F.softmax(actor(states)).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()

